# Python: pattern matching(?)

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I am a beginner in Python programming and I have a question about constructing a code.

Let's say I have the following data:

```
150 z   Brazil
160 a   Toys R Us
```

I want to code such that if we see the pattern `bbb \t (one digit or character not a) \t`, I would replace the `bbb \t digit \t` with `bbb_$d$_`. (Here, `\t` indicates tab and `bbb` indicates a number).

Thus, the output would be `150_$z$_Brazil`, and the output for `160 a   Toys R Us` would not be obtained as the digit after `160` is `a`.

My question is, how do I code such that I select one digit or character that is not `a`?

Comment: Text pattern matching like this is often done with [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto). Regular expressions can get (very) complicated, but they can be useful even if you just learn a few of the basics. Sometimes if your data is more structured, you can get by with simpler things like `mytext.split('\t')`

Comment: @Marius: Doesn't regex require the output to be in list form? I saw the link and watched some tutorials on regex but seems like the output is in a form of a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q. how do I code such that I select one digit or character that is not a?

A.  `'[^a]'`

The regular expression syntax is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: Doesn't regex require the output to be in list form? I saw the link and watched some tutorials on regex but seems like the output is in a form of a list.